# Compare 2 numpy arrays get positional difference

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, indexing, numpy-ndarray

So i have two arrays as shown in the example below:

```
import os
import numpy as np

tiA = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2]) * 1000
tiB = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2]) * 1000

res = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(tiB)
                            if elem != tiA[idx]]
print(res)
```

It gives me an answer of [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]. However i wanted to get position 3 and position 9 or [2,8] as an answer because 0.3 and 0.9 is missing from tiB compared to tiA. Also how can i use this answer to select a 4d array. So my array is sized arrayA=(128x128x5xtiA). However i want my new array to be sized arrayB=(128x128x5xtiB) selected from tiA. So basically arrayB will be missing [2,8] of the 4th dimension as shown in my example as compared to arrayA. My problem is most of the time there can be multiple differences (1,2,3 missing) between tiA and tiB. Thank you for all your help.

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was already a good start, but you need to check if the element is not in the other list and not if the elements at the same position are equal.

```
import numpy as np


tiA = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2]) * 1000
tiB = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2]) * 1000

res = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(tiA) if elem not in tiB]
print(res)
```

For the second part you should be able to use `np.delete`. You just need to define the indices (res) and the correct axis (should be 3 in your case then).

```
arrayB = np.delete(arrayA, res, 3))
```

Comment: Can you share some code that will give the answer please?  Also basically i wanted to get a new arrayB of size (128x128x5x18) as per my example so this array will have arrayA (128x128x5x20) minus 3rd and 9th 3D array.

Comment: I added the code for the second part, didn't really understand at first. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Learnt something new today.